# Play again button doesn't work

Tags: xcode, swift, uibutton, sprite-kit

When I press the play again button it doesn't work. I just have this code involving the play again button. What should I add here? How can I add a function to `playAgain` button?  Here is my code:

```
  let playAgain: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(-10, 400, 400, 150))
   playAgain.setTitle("Play Again", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
   playAgain.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 50)
     playAgain.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            playAgain.tag = 1
            self.view!.addSubview(playAgain)
```

Comment: What does your `buttonAction` implementation look like?

Comment: I haven't buttonAction. I don't know how can I use that.

Comment: You need to implement your buttonAction: 
 `func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!)
{
    //Your code here when you press the playAgain button
    println("Button tapped")
}`

This method will be called when you press your playAgain button, just implement it in your view controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a function with any name you like, like this:

```
func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    // do something
}
```

Then set this function as the action of your button:

```
playAgain.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: Where should I add these codes? Should I add in to didMoveToView?

Comment: Put the function anywhere in your view controller, for example right underneath `viewDidLoad`. My second piece of code was a replacement of the fourth line of code you shared (also with `playAgain.addTarget(...`).

Comment: It's working, thank you. Actually, I have one more question. For example I have a **func** which name is **setupGame()**. When I press the play again button, It should worked **setupGame()**. Where should I add this **func**?

Comment: Just use `"setupGame"` as the `action` argument in the `addTarget` call. :)